# Converting tick data into candle chart

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a time series data for each minute. I would like to convert into candle chart of 5 minutes. Sharing the **Input**

```
library(lubridate)
dft <- data.frame(date <- ymd_hms("2011-01-02 09:30:00") + minutes(1:100),rnorm(100, 4,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real familiar with candle charts, so I took every 5th minute from the data, then converted to an `xts` object.

```
# assign times to rownames
set.seed(321)
dft <- data.frame(val=rnorm(100, 4, 2))
rownames(dft) <- ymd_hms("2011-01-02 09:30:00") + minutes(1:100)

# every 5th minute
dft5 <- dft[seq(1, nrow(dft), by=5), , drop=F]

# candle chart
require(quantmod)
candleChart(as.xts(dft5))
```

[image]